# How to pass ausername of the current logged in user on url? python django

Tags: python, django

I'm trying to get all the post by a single user and display it using `DetailView` and I also want to pass the username of the user on the URL.

this is my urls.py:

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ProfileDetail
from . import views

urlpatterns = [
   path('<str:username>/', ProfileDetail.as_view(), name = 'profile'),
]
```

this is my views.py:

```
from django.views.generic import (DetailView)
from django.shortcuts import render , redirect, get_object_or_404
from django.contrib.auth.models import User
from blog.models import Post


class ProfileDetail(DetailView):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'users/myprofile.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author = user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

I have a class-based view almost exactly just like this one and it is working.
This one always gives me this AttributeError: `Generic detail view ProfileDetail must be called with either an object pk or a slug in the URLconf.`

Comment: If you always expect `username` to be in the URL, then `self.kwargs['username']` is better than `self.kwargs.get('username')`, because `get()` can silently return `None` which will cause a more confusing error later.

Answer (score 1):

If you want to display multiple posts, then a `ListView` with `model = Post` would be more suitable.

```
from django.views.generic import ListView

class ProfileDetail(List):
    model = Post
    template_name = 'users/myprofile.html'
    context_object_name = 'posts'
    paginate_by = 5

    def get_queryset(self):
        user = get_object_or_404(User, username=self.kwargs.get('username'))
        return Post.objects.filter(author = user).order_by('-date_posted')
```

Alternatively, if you want to use `DetailView`, then you should have `model = User` because you are showing the posts for a single user. You can avoid the "must be called with either an object pk or a slug" error by overriding `get_object`.

```
from django.views.generic import DetailView

class ProfileDetail(ListView):
    model = User
    template_name = 'users/myprofile.html'

    def get_object(self):
        return User.objects.get(username=self.kwargs['username'])
```

Then, in the template, you can loop over the user's posts with something like:

```
{% for post in user.post_set.all %}
{{ post }}
{% endfor %}
```

Note that by switching to `DetailView`, you lose the pagination features of `ListView`.